# jQuery To Add Classes Based On URL

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to add classes to certain elements. It's necessary because I'm using blogger, and there is only 1 template that I'm allowed to edit. I have the script working just find, but when I try to add more to it, it won't work.

For example, this works:

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
        case '/':
          $('.nav-home').addClass('current');
          break;
        case '/p/about.html':
          $('.nav-about').addClass('current');
          break;
        case '/search/blog':
          $('.nav-blog').addClass('current');
          break;
```

This breaks:

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
        case '/':
          $('.nav-home').addClass('current');
          break;
        case '/p/about.html':
          $('.nav-about').addClass('current');
          break;
        case '/search/blog':
          $('.nav-blog').addClass('current');
          break;
        case '/search/blog':
          $('.post').addClass('masonry');
          break;
```

Also, is there a way that if not specified, add class to nav-blog?

Non-working example:

```
    case 'ANY OTHER URL':
      $('.nav-blog').addClass('current');
      break;
```

Thanks.

Comment: `case 'ANY OTHER URL':` should be `default` [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: Haha for the first ans still the count is '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove two options for switching like

```
case '/search/blog':
      $('.nav-blog').addClass('current');
      $('.post').addClass('masonry');
      break;
```

now try to add another.You are duplicating the cases for '/search/blog'

Answer (score 3):

```
case '/search/blog':
    $('.nav-blog').addClass('current');
    break;
case '/search/blog':
    $('.post').addClass('masonry');
```

you duplicated your case